# Unterschied zwischen den Indefinitivartikeln „manch-“ und „einig-“

Tags: difference, usage, article

Ich lerne Deutsch und ich helfe mir oft mit Italienisch, aber ich kann nicht verstehen, ob es Unterschiede zwischen den Indefinitivartikeln *manch-* und *einig-* gibt oder nicht. Kann mir jemand helfen?

Comment: Zwei Hinweise: 1) muss es *zwischen den* (Dativ Plural) heißen; 2) die Worstellung *kann mir jemand helfen* ist natürlicher. *Mir* ist kürzer als *jemand* und keines von beiden ist sonderlich »neu«, deswegen »zieht« es *mir* nach vorne.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ja, es gibt einen Unterschied.

*Manche* unterstellt ein Teil eines Ganzen. *Einige* unterstellt mehrere ähnliche oder zusammengehörende Teile, die aber nicht zu einem größeren Ganzen gehören müssen.

> Ich habe einige Fragen. (Gut)
> *Ich habe manche Fragen. (Ohne Kontext sicherlich falsch; mit Kontext wahrscheinlich)
>
> Einige Fragen auf German.Stackexchange.com habe ich gestellt. (Gut)
> Manche Fragen auf German.Stackexchange.com habe ich gestellt. (Geht)
>
> Einige Fragen wurden beantwortet. (Gut)
> Manche Fragen wurden beantwortet. (Auch gut, aber leicht andere Bedeutung)

Bei diesem Beispiel sagt der erste Satz nur aus, dass Fragen beantwortet wurden; nicht ob es *alle* Fragen waren oder nur ein Teil. Der zweite Satz stellt unmissverständlich klar, dass auch einige Fragen *nicht* beantwortet wurden.

> <strike>Einig eine Frage …</strike> (Sehr falsch)
> Manch eine Frage … (Feststehende Wendung)

*Manch eine(s/r) kann niemals durch *einig* ersetzt werden.

Comment: Den Singular betreffend hast Fu natürlich recht, deine Ausführungen zum Plural finde ich nicht erhellend.

Comment: Hmm … Wenn *manche Fragen* beantwortet wurden, klingt das für mich nach „weniger“ als *einige Fragen*.

Comment: @Jan, ich danke dir, sehen wir, ob ich verstanden habe oder nicht! 
Z.b.: ----"ich habe mehrere Fehler gemacht, manche Fehler sind schwerwiegender" oder "Habe ich Fehler gemacht? Ja, leider hast du einige Fehler gemacht" oder "ich habe einige Dinge, die dich interessieren, bist du daran interessiert? ja, wahrscheinlich wird es manche Dinge, die mich interessieren, geben"---- Richtig?

Comment: @mle Bis auf, dass der Akkusativ Plural *einige Ding**e** /manche Ding**e*** ist, richtig ^^

Comment: @Jan, Dankeschön! :)

Answer (score 2):

„Manche“ impliziert, dass es auch andere gibt, für die die Aussage nicht zutrifft (insofern ist Jans Formulierung als „Teil des Ganzen“ auf dem richtigen Weg).

„Ich gehe mit einigen Freunden ins Kino“ ist die übliche Formulierung für einen Kinobesuch, wohingegen „Ich gehe mit manchen Freunden ins Kino“ danach klingt, als würde ich die genannten nur nebenbei erwähnen und eigentlich gerade implizit sagen wollen, dass es welche gibt, mit denen ich wohl eher nicht ins Kino gehen würde.

„Manche Früchte schmecken mir besonders gut“, klingt sehr danach, als wolle man implizieren, dass es auch andere gibt, die einem ganz klar nicht schmecken.  Mit „einige Früchte“ ist keine Aussage über unerwünschtes Obst getroffen.